# SpringBoot Web conflicting with SpringBoot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-boot-actuator

I have recently updated a SpringBoot application from using Spring Starter 2.1.0-RELEASE to 2.7.14.

Apart from minor changes, I've been struggling with one dependency, `spring-boot-starter-actuator`, which I require to expose JMX endpoints of the app (such as `health`) used to monitor the app status and health.

There are 2 cases:

1. If I add `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency and `spring-boot-starter-web`, this results in the Tomcat server to never start and the Spring application actually hangs and needs to be killed manually (kill -9).
2. If `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency is not part of the following POM, the app runs normally, Tomcat Server starts and everything runs smoothly but JMX endpoints are not exposed and the app can't be monitored.

Question:

**Is there any conflict / known issue of having both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator` in a pom.xml for Spring Start 2.7.14 ?**

The said pom.xml below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>MyWebServer - Example</name>
    <groupId>org.jones.robert</groupId>
    <artifactId>wbs</artifactId>
    <version>1000-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <vertx.version>3.9.16</vertx.version>
        <activemq.version>5.18.2</activemq.version>
        <mockito.version>4.5.1</mockito.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.36</slf4j.version>
        <jackson.version>2.15.2</jackson.version>
        <spring-project.version>2.7.14</spring-project.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.220</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cache2k</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache2k-base-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.1-jre</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>6.1</version> <!-- Use newer version of ASM -->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.9</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <condor-version>${project.version}</condor-version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/public/</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${project.basedir}/../management-console-ui/dist/</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>codeQuality</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                            <trace>true</trace>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <id>spotbugs</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <reporting>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                            <trace>true</trace>
                        </configuration>
                        <reportSets>
                            <reportSet>
                                <reports>
                                    <report>spotbugs</report>
                                </reports>
                            </reportSet>
                        </reportSets>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </reporting>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: have you tried to remove `.m2` repository and retry ? also `mvn clean install` the same question.

Comment: @AndreiLisa Yes, I did both, and also built the project on completely new machine but it resulted in the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

I've never really found the root cause for this, but the solution was to use `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure` instead of `spring-boot-actuator`.

This avoided any conflict with `spring-boot-starter-web` and allowed to have the JMX endpoints exposed.